# How to handle list records with square brackets

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Trying to call api with python script. My data resides in list and comes with square brackets. API is expecting curly braces

I have some records in list as below

```
[[1, '12334', 'test1', '10', '20', '30', '2000', '5/15/2019', '35.7', '101', 'TRUE'], [2, '56789', 'Test2', '10', '20', '35', '10000', '6/20/2019', '120.99', '102', 'FALSE'], [3, '67890', 'Test3', '10', '20', '40', '1000', '7/20/2019', '100.99', '103', 'FALSE']]
```

I will be running python3 script to call api with above data.This list will be passed as json to call api

api is receving format as -

```
{
  "testInputs": [
    {
      "testId": 1,
      "testitem": 12334,
      "Name": "Test1",
      "dn": 10,
      "dt": 20,
      "cs": 30,
      "in": 2000,
      "op": "2019-05-15",
      "re": 35.7,
      "nr": 101,
      "anni: true
    },
    {
      "testId": 2,
      "testitem": 56789,
      "Name": "Test2",
      "dn": 10,
      "dt": 20,
      "cs": 35,
      "in": 10000,
      "op": "2019-06-20",
      "re": 120.99,
      "nr": 102,
      "anni": false
    }
  ]
}
```

When I pass list records in json.dump and call api it comes with square bracket-- like

```
{"testInputs": [[1, "78901", "Test1", "10", "20", "45", "3000", "8/20/2019", "50.99", "104", "TRUE"], [2, "89012", "Test2", "10", "20", "50", "4000", "7/20/2019", "60.99", "105", "FALSE"], [3, "90123", "Test3", "10", "20", "55", "5000", "7/15/2019", "70.99", "106", "FALSE"]]}
```

How to get records in curly braces to match format of api ?

Comment: `zip` with a list of keys, pass to `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of the keys that you want:

```
keys = ["testId", "testitem", ..., "nr", "anni"]
```

If your input list, let's call it `data`, always has items in the right order, you can make a dictionary by zipping the keys and the values together:

```
result = [dict(zip(keys, d)) for d in data]
```

You seem to be looking for an additional layer of dictionary:

```
{"testInputs": result}
```

OR

```
{"testInputs": [dict(zip(keys, d)) for d in data]}
```

Comment: Thank you.. It will help in this scenario

Comment: The proper way to thank in this context is by selecting the answer but clicking on the check make next to it

Comment: I did that but seems its not accepting as I am new user

Comment: You can always accept. Sometimes you have to wait a day